# j2ee-update table values even unfortunately closed browser or tap

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, browser

I want to update database table value even while closing browser/tap.Here is my code which is not satisfied me.

Home.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login success!...</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( window ).unload(function() {

    $.post( "BrowserCloseServlet", function( ) {

    });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

BrowserCloseServlet.java :

```
 import java.io.IOException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import com.sun.corba.se.spi.orb.ParserImplBase;




    /**
     * Servlet implementation class BrowserCloseServlet
     */
    @WebServlet("/BrowserCloseServlet")
    public class BrowserCloseServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public BrowserCloseServlet() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

String getId = request.getParameter("getid");
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement pst = null;
            PreparedStatement pst2 = null;
            ResultSet rst = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/raptor1_5","root","");
                String query ="select NoOfCount from tbl_BroserCloseTable ";
                String query2 ="update tbl_BroserCloseTable set NoOfCount= ? where Sno= ?";
                //Statement st = con.createStatement();
                //st.executeUpdate("");
                pst = con.prepareStatement(query);

                rst = pst.executeQuery(query);
                if(rst.next())
                {
                    int count = rst.getInt(1);
                    System.out.println("Actuall count is :"+count);
                    count -= 1; 

                    pst2 = con.prepareStatement(query2);
                    pst2.setInt(1, count);
                    pst2.setInt(2, 1);
                    pst2.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("Updated successfully...");


                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                try {
                    con.close();
                    rst.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }



        }

    }
```

Nothing happen when i run the code and close the browse or tap.

someone tell me how to call the BrowserCloseServlet.java and make updates while closing browser/tap.

Where i am wrong?

Comment: The root cause of this is `$( window ).unload`. You should learn about the [JQuery .unload()](https://api.jquery.com/unload/). This link will tell you when the unload event is fired.

Comment: & one thing is u r calling `$.post` in `.jsp` & on the servlet side `doPost` is blank. Why this is so ? What r u trying to do ? I think ur business logic should go inside `doPost` method in `BrowserCloseServlet`. Let's try this.

Comment: So what is the status then ? Are u using servlet 3 ? Do u get any exception ? If yes, then please add it to question.

Comment: @OO7 I changed it but thats not exact problem. Problem is BrowserCloseServlet not calling while closing window. so what correct event i should use here?

Comment: See ur `@WebServlet` name is `BrowserCloseServlet` & u have specified `BroserCloseServlet` in `$.post`. **`w` is missing**.

Comment: I changed that too but no use.

Comment: Even i tried with $( window ).beforeunload but no use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74922/discussion-between-m-manivasagam-and-oo7).